# Execute function before application gets quit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to call a function before processing the stop/kill signal.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle a `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` signal by setting-up a signal handler (see [`signal(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/signal.3.html)), however you cannot *handle* `SIGKILL`, which is why it should be the last resort to use against a program.

If you always want to do something before the process exits, then see [`atexit(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/atexit.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/atexit).

```
$ cat sig.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void closedown() {
    printf("running closedown\n");
}

static void sighandler(int signal) {
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    signal(SIGTERM, sighandler);
    signal(SIGINT, sighandler);
    atexit(closedown);
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("tick\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

$ clang -o sig sig.c
$ ./sig
tick
tick
^Crunning closedown
```